# Sitting text beneath image link using codeigniter

Tags: html, css, image, codeigniter

Ok, kind of silly question, but I can't get this to work for the life of me. I'm trying to position text beneath my navigation images.

I have tried putting the text in spans, paragraphs and even tried break tags.

This is my ul

```
<ul id="mainImg">
  <li><?=anchor('home/artwork', $art); ?></li>
  <li><?=anchor('home/comps', $des); ?></li>
  <li><?=anchor('home/sites', $web); ?></li>
</ul>
```

I am using codeigniter so the images are being stored in variables and then I'm passing them into the links above so that they are clickable.

The only styles I have on these three images is an opacity and a display:inline on the li so that they sit next to each other. With each attempt to put text below them it pushes the rest of the images to the next line as well. I would like to avoid this if at all possible.

I do have a live site that this is sitting on if you would like to see what I am trying to accomplish. catlyndesigns.net Keep in mind I am currently recoding the entire backend of this site so little to nothing is working at the moment.

Thank you for all your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead.

Example:
http://codepen.io/jonjaques/pen/JvocB

Notice that I use a span inside of the anchor tag, because it's more semantic. You could use a `<p>` tag too, the important thing is the element that wraps the text needs to have `display: block`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just trying the p tag just make sure I wasn't missing anything. I have a habit of trying anything and everything before asking. haha